# cant get finnhub.io calendar earnings like in the example

Tags: finnhub

im trying to get 5 years of symbol earnings calendar in finnhub.io, but i am not able.
tried to use the url in their documentation, but its not working.
any idea how to solve this ?

tried:

url = f'https://finnhub.io/api/v1/calendar/earnings?from=2022-03-01&to=2023-03-09&symbol=AAPL&token={FINNHUB_KEY}' - returns empty list

url = f'https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/earnings?symbol=AAPL&from={from_unix_timestamp}&to={to_unix_timestamp}&token={FINNHUB_KEY}' - returns only last year

url = f'https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/earnings?symbol=AAPL&from=2022-03-01&to=2022-03-09&token={FINNHUB_KEY}' - returns only last year

also tried to use the python package, but same result.

plz help.
thnx

Answer (score 0):

this is really stupid, but apparently the calendar/earnings endpoint or the finnhub_client.earnings_calendar method is only for future earnings. passed ones are not listed.
which is strange, cause there is "eps actual" and "revenue actual" field there.
and they cant exist if its in the future